# Self Submit PHP Form Validation

Tags: php, html, forms, contact-form

I've made a PHP form to submit to self with error validation, but the form is not submitting. The idea is, when the user clicks on the *submit* button and hasn't filled in all required fields or email address they entered is flawed, then errors occur by adding an error class that's sorted by CSS. The CSS is fine, but the form is not submitting. I'd appreciate the help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Email</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        $error = '';
        $to = "name@example.com";

        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            if (empty($_POST["name"]) || empty($_POST["email"]) || empty($_POST["message"])) {
                $error = 'class="error" ';
            } else {
                $name = stripslashes(trim($_POST["name"]));
                $email = stripslashes(trim($_POST["email"]));
                $message = stripslashes(trim($_POST["message"]));
                $pattern = '/[\r\n]|Content-Type:|Bcc:|Cc:/i';

                if (preg_match($pattern, $name) || preg_match($pattern, $email)) {
                    $error = 'class="error" ';
                }

                $emailIsValid = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

                if ($name && $email && $emailIsValid && $message) {
                    $subject = "From $name";
                    $body = "Name: $name <br /> Email: $email <br /> Message: $message";

                    $headers = "Reply-To: $email";

                    $success = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
                    if ($success) {
                        header("Location: /email/sent/");
                    } else {
                        header("Location: /error/");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ?>

        <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); ?>">
            <input <?php echo $error; ?>type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" spellcheck="false">
            <input <?php echo $error; ?>type="text" email="email" placeholder="Email Address" spellcheck="false">
            <textarea <?php echo $error; ?>type="text" message="message" placeholder="Message" rows="6" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
            <button type="submit" name="submitted">submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have an error here: name="email" ..... <input <?php echo $error; ?>type="text" email="email"

Comment: You have similar error here: <textarea <?php echo $error; ?>type="text" MESSAGE="message" should be name="message"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE :** You have typo mistakes in your form tag.you used double quote inside double quote.

Insted of using this

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); ?>">
and
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
```

Use

```
<form method="post" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
and
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['submitbutton'])) {
//SO IT WILL PERFORM ONLY WHEN SUBMIT BUTTON WAS PRESSED
```

For More You can Learn it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp)

Or Also **[Live Demo](https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_validation_complete)** is available

Comment: there is no issue with the double quotes inside the double quotes. the php variable will be parsed without a problem.